# How to let my customers login to Shopify via third-party account (without Multipass)

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, shopify

I want my customers to be able to login to my Shopify store via my existing website account system.

This means that if they've already entered their address on my website, they don't need to enter it again in Shopify. (And if I can also track my users' shopping behaviour that would be a bonus.)

I found this related discussion on the Shopify forums (about Facebook login), but with no clear answer:
https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/login-with-facebook-114126

Is it possible to use oAuth (or some other method) to enable this kind of functionality in Shopify?

Answer (score 3):

The official Shopify method to login to your store from your third-party website is to use [*Multipass*](https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/multipass), however this requires a [Shopify Plus](https://www.shopify.com/plus) account (starting at $995/month).

Shopify does provide *some* support for oAuth, however it appears to be mainly used for shop-owners adding third-party apps into their stores, not for creating customer accounts.

There are various apps available for social login functionality. While these won't exactly provide the functionality you need, they must have a found a way of creating new user accounts, so perhaps they can hint at a possible solution for this.

See https://apps.shopify.com/search/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=log+in